# Angular JS : Insert one directive into another directive dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

First of all, the way i am doing may not be correct. But i will explain the problem:

1) I am creating directive called as < firstDirective >

2) when the clicks on a button in the first directive, then I am trying to insert the second directive dynamically at runtime

As follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">

<first-directive></first-directive>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.directive("firstDirective", function() {
    return {
       template : '<h1>This is first directive!</h1> <br / ><br / ><button type="button" ng-click="firstCtrl()">Click Me to second directive!</button> <div id="insertSecond"></div> ',
        controller: function ($scope) {
              $scope.firstCtrl = function($scope) {
                    angular.element(document.querySelector('#insertSecond')).append('<second-directive></second-directive>');                  
              } 
        }
    }
});        

app.directive("secondDirective", function() {
    return {
       template : '<h1>This is second directive!</h1> <br / ><br / >',
        controller: function ($scope) {

        }
    }
});        


 </body>
 </html>
```

But it is not working, i mean, it is inserting the "< second-directive > < / second-directive >" text but not the content as per the directive above.

I am new to angular js, I think we can do this in a different way or my approach itself is not correct. But all i want to insert the second directive dynamically.

**EDIT::** I got the solution for this, thanks to the George Lee:

Solution is we have to compile as follows, but didn’t pass scope object to the function:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">

<first-directive></first-directive>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.directive("firstDirective", function($compile) {
    return {
       templateUrl : '<h1>This is first directive!</h1> <br / ><br / ><button type="button" ng-click="firstCtrl()">Click Me to second directive!</button> <div id="insertSecond"></div> ',
        controller: function ($scope) {
              $scope.firstCtrl = function() {
                    var ele = $compile('<second-directive></second-directive>')($scope);
                    angular.element(document.querySelector('#insertSecond')).append(ele);                  
              } 
        }
    }
});        

app.directive("firstDirective", function() {
    return {
       templateUrl : '<h1>This is second directive!</h1> <br / ><br / >',
        controller: function ($scope) {

        }
    }
});
```

Also, this [link](http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-dynamic-templates/) , gives very good explanation of how to dynamically compile and inject the templates.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`$compile`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) service in Angular, make sure you include it in the dependency injection.

```
app.directive("firstDirective", ['$compile', function($compile) {
...
controller: function ($scope) {
    $scope.firstCtrl = function() {
         var ele = $compile('<second-directive></second-directive>')($scope);
         angular.element(document.querySelector('#insertSecond')).append(ele);                  
    } 
}
```

Comment: I done as you specified above, it is throwing error saying like, "  Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'scope' is required ", check this link : https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ng/areq?p0=scope&p1=required

Comment: Try removing `$scope` function argument from `firstCtrl` function. So... `$scope.firstCtrl = function() { ...`

Comment: Great :) thanks buddy i got it. After removing the $scope element from the firstctrl function. But one more thing Lee, we didnot have to inject $compile as you said, we can simply use, like this from Angular JS Documentation: " app.directive("firstDirective", function($compile) { " In this way, it is working fine. I am rating you up.

Comment: That is dependency injection as well and is implicit on the function argument name. Your dependency injection will break if you minify your js file and it renames the parameter. It is "best practice" to define as how I have in my answer, then it doesn't matter what the argument name is.

Comment: Yes, you are right @George Lee, it is working with the compile injection also.

Answer (score 0):

There is one more problem instead of templateUrl, template should be there

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
        <script data-require="angular.js@1.0.x" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.0.8"></script>
```

```
         <first-directive></first-directive>

     <script>
      var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
          app.directive("firstDirective", function($compile) {
              return {
              template : '<h1>This is first directive!</h1> <br / ><br / ><button type="button" ng-click="firstCtrl()">Click Me to second directive!</button> <div id="insertSecond"></div> ',
              controller: function ($scope) {
              $scope.firstCtrl = function() {
                var ele = $compile('<second-directive></second-directive>')($scope);
                angular.element(document.querySelector('#insertSecond')).append(ele);
             }
         },
          restrict: "EAC"

   }
```

});

```
          app.directive("secondDirective", function() {
             return {
             template : '<h1>This is second directive!</h1> <br / ><br / >',
             controller: function ($scope) {

       },
             restrict: "EAC"
    }
  });
     </script>
   </body>
 </html>
```