# Angular JS How to insert custom Directives in the Bootstrap UI Tabs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

As per [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34732189/angular-js-insert-one-directive-into-another-directive-dynamically), i am able to insert one directive into another directive successfully. But now, when i am using the same way to put the directive in the tabs as follows, I am unable to compile the directive properly and it is showing me **UNKNOWN CHARACTERS** like :: `{"0":{"ng339":6},"length":1}`

Please note that:
1) I used the example from the [Angular UI BootStrap Tabs](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tabs)

```js
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
        angular.module('myapp')
      .controller('myCtrl',['$scope','$compile', function ($scope, $compile) {

      $scope.tabs = [
        { title:'Dynamic Title 1', content:'<first-directive></first-directive>' },
        { title:'Dynamic Title 2', content:'Dynamic content 2' }
      ];
      var compileTabs = function() {
        var ele = $compile($scope.tabs[0].content)($scope);
        $scope.tabs[0].content = ele;
      };

      compileTabs();
       
      $scope.model = {
        name: 'Tabs'
      };
    }]);


angular.module('myapp').directive("firstDirective",['$compile', function($compile) {
    return {
        templateUrl : './directives/firstdirective.html',
         scope: {
            },
        controller: function ($scope) {
            
            $scope.firstCtrl = function() 
            {
              console.log('I am in the firstCtrl');
            }
    }}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp">

<head>
    <title>AngularJS: UI-Router Quick Start</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body class="container">
  
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <uib-tabset>
      <uib-tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" active="tab.active" disable="tab.disabled">
        {{tab.content}}
      </uib-tab>
  </uib-tabset>

</div>
  

<script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>

<script src="lib/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the tab content was incorrect. it should be <first-directive></first-directive>

Comment: @sdfacre i am sorry it is typo, when i am writing the code on the stackoverflow, it mismatched. I am updating the code, but please note that, with that also, i am getting the result of that UNKNOWN CHARACTERS only.

Comment: got it. I am not sure why you want to do this, but when you manual compile your directive, the outcome is an object, that's why the content shows as object. if you really want to do this, try $scope.tabs[0].content = ele.html();. Also, be aware of, if you are doing it this way, you actually extract the html content of your directive and put it under tab, so it will be just some static html.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just forgot definitions of the services.

### Your code

```
.controller('myCtrl',['$compile', function ($scope, $window, $compile) {
```

`$window` and `$compile` will be `undefined`.

### Right code

```
.controller('myCtrl',['$scope', '$window', '$compile', function ($scope, $window, $compile) {
```

Comment: I am sorry i didnot updated the question, please check now, i inject the services properly. Then also, compile is compiling into some "unknown caharcters" like this : {"0":{"ng339":6},"length":1}